# Send HTTP request and get response using ZeroMQ

Tags: php, api, rest, zeromq

Is there any way to send http request and get response from server.

For Ex. - i want to send request to my http server http://xx.xx.xx.xx, after processing request i need a reply from same server.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check [Zurl](https://github.com/fanout/zurl): it's a server that makes HTTP requests for you. You talk to Zurl via ZeroMQ (a PUSH socket to submit requests and a SUB socket to retrieve responses), and Zurl backend asynchronously sends HTTP requests and retrieves HTTP replies using libcurl.

For an introduction, see the blog post: ["Make HTTP requests over ZeroMQ with Zurl"](http://blog.fanout.io/2012/09/26/make-http-requests-over-zeromq-with-zurl/).